# R Find all replies to a user's tweets from their follower list

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I'm trying to find out the number of replies for all given tweets by a user. This is not something avaiable directly from Twitter's API. I've decided to only go after replies from a user's followers, to help distill down the data generated and as a good approximation (I believe msot of the replies to a tweet will come directly from that users followers.

I believe I've come a long way already, I jsut need help with the final section. I'm struggling to make the function I've created run over all the followers.

I'd rather this solution be in R over Python, although I know this exists and will be an option. I've also put in the twitter tag for Donald Trump; I'm not trying to do it for him and know that his huge following will make this a challenge. I want a generic version useable for whichever user is inputted.

```
library(rtweet)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

##set name of tweeter to look at (this can be changed)
targettwittername <- "realDonaldTrump"

##get this tweeter's timeline
tmls <- get_timeline(targettwittername, n=3200, retryonratelimit=TRUE)
##get their user id
targettwitteruserid <- as.numeric(select(lookup_users(targettwittername), user_id))
##get ids of their tweets
tweetids <- select(tmls, status_id)
tweetids <- transform(tweetids, status_id_num=as.numeric(status_id))

##get list of followers (who are most likely to reply)
targetfollowers <- data.frame(get_followers(targettwittername))

##clean up follower list to exclude those that have never tweeted and restricted access
user_lookup <- lookup_users(targetfollowers)
users_with_tweets_and_unprotected <- filter(user_lookup, statuses_count != 0)
users_with_tweets_and_unprotected <- select(filter(users_with_tweets_and_unprotected, protected != "TRUE"), user_id)

targetfollowers <- filter(targetfollowers, user_id %in% users_with_tweets_and_unprotected$user_id)



##custom function to search all followers timelines one by one
getfollowersreplies <- function(x){
  follower <- as.numeric(x[1])
  followertl <- data.frame(get_timeline(follower, n=3200, retryonratelimit=TRUE))
  followertl <- filter(followertl, in_reply_to_status_user_id == targettwitteruserid)
  followertl <- transform(followertl, reply_to_status_id_num=as.numeric(in_reply_to_status_status_id))
  join <- inner_join(followertl, tweetids, by=c("reply_to_status_id_num"="status_id_num"))
  replycounts <- data.frame(
                  join %>%
                    group_by(user_id, reply_to_status_id_num) %>%
                    summarise(n=n())
                  )
  return(replycounts)
}


tweet_replies <- do.call("rbind", lapply(targetfollowers$user_id, getfollowersreplies))
```

Comment: What does "I'm struggling to make the function I've created run over all the followers." mean? What exactly is the struggle?

Comment: @ThomasK I've created the function getfollowersreplies in the above code. This function is working fine when I step through with a single user_id, however when I try to use lapply and this function it doesn't work. Hopefully this has made it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest obstacle would be the time it takes to collect up to 3,200 of the most recent tweets posted by more than 42 million followers of [@realDonaldTrump](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump).

```
> djt <- lookup_users(targettwittername)
> djt[, c("screen_name", "followers_count", "friends_count", "statuses_count")]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
      screen_name followers_count friends_count statuses_count
            <chr>           <int>         <int>          <int>
1 realDonaldTrump        42793758            45          36398
```

Twitter limits the number of follower user IDs collected to 75,000 every 15 minutes.

```
flw <- get_followers("realDonaldTrump", n = 75000)
> flw
# A tibble: 75,000 x 1
              user_id
                <chr>
 1          928808378
 2 926186565231136768
 3 931237514253426688
 4 930584682701475842
 5 902580952165216256
 6 931236663950372864
 7 931237367024820224
 8 922140807024578560
 9 931235142047211520
10 931235653412708352
# ... with 74,990 more rows
```

Assuming you have a reliable internet connection and time, then you can use the following code to get all 42 million follower IDs.

```
flw <- get_followers(
  "realDonaldTrump", n = 42793758, retryonratelimit = TRUE
)
```

Then you'd probably want to construct a for loop that uses `get_timeline()` and handles API rate limits. In the example code below, I've made the loop sleep until the rate limit reset after every 56 calls.

```
flw_tml <- vector("list", length(flw$user_id))
for (i in seq_along(flw$user_id)) {
  flw_tml[[i]] <- get_timeline(
    flw$user_id[i], n = 3200
  )
  if (i %% 56 == 0L) {
    rl <- rate_limit("get_timeline")
    Sys.sleep(as.numeric(rl$reset, "secs"))
  }
  cat(i, " ")
}
```

As you can see, this would take a really long time. You'd be better off trying to collect all the replies in the past 6-9 days. The code below gets up to 5 million replies to Trump's tweets from the past 9 days. Warning: if there are actually that many replies (I honestly have no idea) available from the past 9 days, this search would take just under three days to finish.

```
at_rdt <- search_tweets(
  "to:realdonaldtrump", 
  n = 5e6,
   retryonratelimit = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's good to see the definitive way of doing this. I completely agree that doing this method on someone like Donald Trump is completely impractical, this username was only put in for the sake of argument.

The problem I had with this final approach was that I needed more than 6-9 days worth of results. I've since got this information from web-scraping, but your first response is also excellent!

Comment: Excellent! Well, for future reference: if you can scrape the HTML source files saved from manually searching and then scrolling twitter.com in a web browser, then you might find the `lookup_statuses()` function useful. Just parse out the "tweet-id" param values from the source code and pass them to `lookup_statuses(tweet_ids)` to get all the Twitter meta data (and text of each tweet) from the REST API (there is no date limit for statuses/lookup).