# Fetching comments from tweets of a single user in R

Tags: r, twitter

I have collected tweets from a single user:

```
api_key <- "XXXX"
api_secret <- "XXXX"
access_token <- "XXXX"
access_token_secret <- "XXXX"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

salvini <- rtweet::get_timeline(user = "matteosalvinimi", n = 3600)
```

From here, I only know how many likes or retweets each tweet has received (respectively through `salvini$favourite_count` and `salvini$retweet_count`). What I would like to do is collecting the text of each of the comments to these tweets.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

First, please review the protocol for asking questions. You got downgraded because you (1) did not provide a reproducible data set and (2) asked a question answered elsewhere here.

Here is a quick answer though:

```
library(twitteR);library(dplyr); library(ROAuth)
#set API Keys; to obtain, go here: https://apps.twitter.com/ and make an application for  your twitter account

api_key <- "paste yours here"      # create a set of 'keys' & 'tokens'
api_secret <- "paste yours here"
access_token <- "paste yours here"
access_token_secret <- "paste yours here"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

#grab latest tweet data
tweets1 <- searchTwitter('@oprah', n=1000)
TweetsBy1<-twListToDF(tweets1)  #convert to dataframe
TweetsBy1$account<-"Oprah"  # useful to have this

glimpse(TweetsBy1) # look at your data; the text variable is what you're after

temp<- TweetsBy1 %>% 
        group_by(created) %>%   # you will need to reformat this date variable
        summarise(numTweets=n())

TweetsBy1$text   # this is the text of the tweets

ggplot(temp, aes(created,numTweets))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
       theme_bw()+ylab("Number of Tweets")+
       ggtitle("Number of Tweets by Date")
```

As for text analysis, that's a whole other ball of wax.  See the `tidytext` package for more info.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your points. I have inserted the code I have used to collect the data. My question does not seem to have appeared in other posts: if I got it right, in your syntax you obtain tweets including the word "@oprah" (which might be interpreted as posts about oprah), and with `TweetsBy1$text` you extract the text. What I meant was collecting the text commenting each of the tweets posted by user "matteosalvinimi". I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: @LucaCarbone  This answer might help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226073/r-find-all-replies-to-a-users-tweets-from-their-follower-list